# Order by integer does not work with my join query

Tags: mysql, join, epoch

I am trying to order my data from the query but it does not seem to order anything. I have the following query:

```
SELECT Sleutelwoord.URL
FROM Sleutelwoord 
LEFT JOIN Artikel ON
    Artikel.URL = Sleutelwoord.URL
    AND Sleutelwoord.TEXT = 'somekeyword'
    ORDER BY Artikel.Datum DESC;
```

The tables:

Artikel                 //=article

```
PK URL varchar(255)   //the url
Datum bigint          //the date
```

Sleutelwoord             //=keyword

```
PK URL varchar(255)  //the url
PK TEXT varchar(255) //the keyword
Aantal int           //amount of keywords
```

I store epoch time (in java as long) inside the 'Datum' row. I want the url's sorted based on the epoch time where the newest (largest) is the first. Why does my query not do this and how can I fix this? Thanks.

EDIT: swapped the article/keyword in the table defenitions.

Lets say I have 3 articles:

```
url1 - 1459336143
url2 - 1459336153
url3 - 1459336161
```

Where url 1 is the first, 2 the second and 3 the last (and newest).

The keyword table would have something like this:

```
url1 - randomword - 1
url1 - anotherword - 1
url1 - duplicateword - 2

url2 - randomword - 1
url2 - anotherword - 1
url2 - duplicateword - 2

url3 - something- 1
url3 - else- 1
url3 - nothing- 2
```

If my keyword is randomword, I want url1 and url2 back, but I want them ordered by the date (epoch). So I want

```
url2
url1
```

because url2 is the newest and url1 is older then url2.

Comment: How it si related to java

Comment: Its not any longer, I changed my contents of the message but forgot to remove the tag.

Comment: are sortable   only value ..in select

Comment: Is `Datum` a field of table `Artikel` (as stated in the query) or of table `Sleutelwoord` (as stated in the tables definition)? If it belongs to `Artikel`, the `LEFT JOIN` produces rows having `NULL` in `Artikel`.`Datum` and they probably don't sort as you expect.

Comment: please provide sample data, actual and expected output from your query.

Comment: Try inner join instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned

```
ORDER BY Artikel.Datum DESC;
```

but for Artikel table Datum is not a column

```
PK URL varchar(255)  //the url
PK TEXT varchar(255) //the keyword
Aantal int           //amount of keywords
```

if you want to order based on Datum, use

```
 ORDER BY Sleutelwoord.Datum DESC;
```

Comment: Include Artikel.Datum in Select and use inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Using INNER JOIN your query will retrieve only rows matched in both tables.

```
SELECT s.URL
FROM Sleutelwoord AS s
INNER JOIN Artikel AS a ON
  a.URL = s.URL
WHERE s.TEXT = 'somekeyword'
ORDER BY a.Datum DESC;
```